# Save little information as setting in android (like first time that app is run)

Tags: java, android, database, application-settings

I want to save a flag for recognizing that my app is run for the first time or not. For this simple job I don't want to create database..

Is there a simple option to do this? I want to save and read little pieces of information only.

Comment: The easiest way to persist information like this is by using [`Preferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).
You can find a great introduction on [Saving Key-Value Sets in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

Comment: SharedPreference is the way to go. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `SharedPreferences`.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefName", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit= preferences.edit();

edit.putBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
edit.commit();
```

Answer (score 58):

Use `sharedPreference` or `files` to save the data but better option is `sharedPreference`.

For Retrieving

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
```

For Saving

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("silentMode", true);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 10):

A proper way to do this is by using the Android class `SharedPreferences` which is used for things like this.

## Storing Settings

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(NAME_OF_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("appPreviouslyStarted", true);
editor.apply();
```

**Don't forget to apply or your mutations to the settings won't be saved!**

You can create multiple settings by using different `NAME_OF_PREFERENCES`. The settings are stored on the device so will be available after closing the application.

When you try to retrieve `NAME_OF_PREFERENCES` that is not already created, you create a new one. See more behavior like this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)).

### apply() versus commit()

You can use `editor.apply()` as well as `editor.commit()`, the only difference is that apply() does not return a `boolean` value with if the edit was successful or not. editor.apply() is therefor faster and more commonly used.

### What is MODE_PRIVATE

You can see all about the different modes [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE). For your case `MODE_PRIVATE` is fine.

## Retrieving settings

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(NAME_OF_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
```

When retrieving a settings from a `SharedPreferences` object you always have to specify a default value which will be returned when the setting was not found. In this case that's `false`.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to go for [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) persistent storage. Its very easy and fast storing/retrival for small amount of information.

See the code to get the value from SharedPreference

```
   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
   setSilent(silent);
```

and to Store value in SharedPreference

```
 // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do one class for example: 
(like a object for instance)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;


public class SettingsMain {

    Context context;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private static final String PREFER_NAME = "settingsMain";
    public static final String KEY_VIBRATE = "switchVibrate";

    public SettingsMain(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        setPreferences();
    }

    private void setPreferences(){
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = preferences.edit();
    }

    public void cleanPreferences(){
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void setStatusVibrate(Boolean status){
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_VIBRATE, status);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public Boolean getstatusVibrate(){
        return preferences.getBoolean(KEY_VIBRATE, true);
    }
}
```

On your activity call:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {


    private SettingsMain settings;
    private SwitchCompat switchVibrate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.master);


        setResources();
        getSettings();

    }

    private void setResources(){

        switchVibrate = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.master_main_body_vibrate_switch);
        switchVibrate.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                settings.setStatusVibrate(isChecked);
            }
        });
    }

    private void getSettings(){
        settings = new SettingsMain(this);
        switchVibrate.setChecked(settings.getstatusVibrate());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using `static` variables globally?

You can do this [as given in this tutorial](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/defining-global-variables-in-android/). I know handling Content providers are unnecessary just to keep some flags.

Else you can check out [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) provided by Android. [Here's a good example](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-application-preferences/) to get started.

This would be my recommendation.