# How to setup agreement page in android

Tags: android

I made an android app and I have added an agreement activity in it.But every time I start the app it starts the agreement page.I want that After the application is installed,it should not show the agreement page every time but a specific activity should be launched.How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
boolean wasShown = prefs.getBoolean("agr", false);
if(!wasShown) {
    showAgr();
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("agr", true).commit();
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am not getting,what you are saying.I have set the agreement as the first activity to be launched when I launch the application.And when app starts,Agreement page come in front of user by default

Comment: Then, check as above in your activity's onCreate and if the agreement has already been shown call finish() and then startActivity for your next activity from within your onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` to identify whether the app is running for the first time.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385117/save-little-information-like-settings-in-android) question